# Why is Invoke-WebRequest not providing the Body?

Tags: powershell

I have a very simple we server that takes a body and outputs it into an html response here is an example using a simple browser wrapper...

[image: Sorry too new for images :-)]

But when I try to invoke [via Powershell's utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) the body comes back empty. Here is the Powershell code...

```
$Body = 'TODO'
# Shows TODO
Write-Host $Body
$LoginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://localhost:8080/ping' -Body $Body -Method 'POST'
# WTF no TODO
Write-Host $LoginResponse
```

...

```
PS ..> .\SendToDashboard.ps1
TODO
<html>
<body>
<h1> Post Pong </h1>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing why is it not using the `-Body` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the content-type header with `-ContentType "text/plain"` to have the same behavior as your sample application.

From the docs for [Invoke-WebRequest ContentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6):

> If this parameter is omitted and the request method is POST, Invoke-WebRequest sets the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Otherwise, the content type is not specified in the call.